# How to create a completely (uniformly) random dataset on PyTorch

Tags: dataset, pytorch

I need to run some experiments on custom datasets using pytorch. The question is, how can I create a dataset using torch.Dataloader?

I have two lists, one is called *Values* and has a datapoint tensor at every entry, and the other one is called *Labels*, that has the corresponding label. What I did is the following:

```
for i in range(samples):
dataset[i] = [values[i],labels[I]]
```

So I have a list with datapoint and respective label, and then tried the following:

```
dataset = torch.tensor(dataset).float()
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(dataset)

data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
```

But, first of all, I get the error "Not a sequence" in the torch.tensor command, and second, I'm not sure this is the right way of creating one. Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to overload `DataLoader`, but rather create a `Dataset` for your data.
For instance,

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyDataset, self).__init__()
    # do stuff here?
    self.values = values
    self.labels = labels

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.values)  # number of samples in the dataset

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.values[index], self.labels[index]
```

Comment: Thanks! one last comment: when I then do 

     my_random = MyDataset(root='./data', 
                            train=True, 
                            transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                            download=True)

I get the error  "   __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root'.  ". Why is that?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Alfred you need to change the signiture of the `__init__` function to include all the arguments you need to construct the dataset

Answer (score 1):

Just to enrich the answer by @shai

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, values):
        super(MyDataset, self).__init__()
        self.values = values

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.values)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.values[index]

values = np.random.rand(51000, 3)

dataset = MyDataset(values)
```